# Can I ask convention based questions on Stackoverflow?

Tags: support, questions, scope, asking-questions

In am learning ASP.Net 5 currently, and I have a few questions about the conventional file structure and where to put specific files. Are questions like this off-topic?

Comment: Try Programmers SE :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Servy said in the [other answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308230/477420) most case will be "opinion based" and hence closed.

Note that there are cases when it would be on-topic like: "does framework XXX require to put YYY files in particular location", "what are default locations for YYY files", "how to change default location for YYY files" may be on topic. I.e. views in ASP.Net MVC have default locations, but all other files/classes can be anywhere - so asking about views will likely be on-topic, asking about models will not.

Unfortunately it is hard to know distinction in advance, especially if it is new framework for you. Phrasing question to look for yes/no answer like "Can I put YYY files anywhere or I must follow convention (all samples show XXX location)" would be more acceptable than "what is better/common/favorite/conventional  place for YYY files".

Comment: My question refers to if I should add TypeScript files to /webroot/js or somewhere else because I am somewhat confused by where the TypeScript compile configuration wants them. Would this fit?

Comment: @James_Parsons unlikely (no restrictions on location of CSS/JS as long as they are HTTP-accessible). Asking why moving ts files to some other folder does not work or how to configure ts to be compiled to folder of your choice would likely be on topic.

Answer (score 10):

Such questions about personal preferences are Primarily Opinion Based, and are thus not on topic on the site.